# HTML appearing before where I call it in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the code below

```
function displayTotalRequestType() {
    echo '<div>';
    echo '  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">';
    echo '    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#today" aria-controls="today" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Today</a></li> ';
    echo '    <li role="presentation"><a href="#week" aria-controls="week" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">This Week</a></li>';
    echo '    <li role="presentation"><a href="#month" aria-controls="month" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">This Month</a></li>';
    echo '  </ul>';
    echo '  <div class="tab-content">';
    echo '    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="today">'.$this->CI->model('custom/Dashboard')->displayTotalRequestTypeTable(date('Y-m-d')).'</div>';
    echo '    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="week">'.$this->CI->model('custom/Dashboard')->displayTotalRequestTypeTable(date("Y-m-d",strtotime('monday this week'))).'</div>';
    echo '    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="month">'.$this->CI->model('custom/Dashboard')->displayTotalRequestTypeTable(date('Y-m-01')).'</div>';
    echo '  </div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

So the function I am calling within this one `($this->CI->model('custom/Dashboard')->displayTotalRequestTypeTable())` displays a table depending on what data I pass into it

However when the page renders, the HTML produced shows the output of `displayTotalRequestTypeTable()` actually start before `<div role="tabpanel"...` and not within the tab as I expected

Any reason? How to resolve?

Comment: Yes - soon realised right after I submitted - thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you are filling all your echoes if $this->CI stuff, why not $this->load->model() and $this->model_name????

Answer (score 1):

Since you are `echo`ing in the function the output displays when you call the function. To control where the output goes, assign the call to a variable, then output the variable where you want it; or `echo displayTotalRequestType();`. e.g.

```
function displayTotalRequestType() {
    return '<div>'.
    '  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">'.
    '    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#today" aria-controls="today" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Today</a></li> '.
    '   <li role="presentation"><a href="#week" aria-controls="week" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">This Week</a></li>'.
    '    <li role="presentation"><a href="#month" aria-controls="month" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">This Month</a></li>'.
    '  </ul>'.
    '  <div class="tab-content">'.
    '    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="today">'.$this->CI->model('custom/Dashboard')->displayTotalRequestTypeTable(date('Y-m-d')).'</div>'.
     '    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="week">'.$this->CI->model('custom/Dashboard')->displayTotalRequestTypeTable(date("Y-m-d",strtotime('monday this week'))).'</div>'.
    '    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="month">'.$this->CI->model('custom/Dashboard')->displayTotalRequestTypeTable(date('Y-m-01')).'</div>'.
    '  </div>'.
    '</div>';
}
```

then in your code,

```
<?php
$requesttype = displayTotalRequestType();
.... //later echo $requesttype;
```

or

```
 echo displayTotalRequestType();
```